# Armenian pH < PIE *p(H)?

Tags: phonetics, sound-change, armenian

PIE * *p* has widely become *h* in Armenian (e.g. հարց (*harts*) "question" < * *prsk*-, հուր (*hur*) "fire" < * *pur*-, etc.). However, some have claimed that the verb փլիլ (*pHlil*) "to fall in, collapse", which begins with aspirated or "fortis" *p*, comes from IE * *pHol-* "fall", i.e. a root with aspirated *p*.

Regardless of whether this etymology is correct (I know that there is some debate around whether PIE had voiceless aspirated stops to begin with), I would have thought that aspirated [p] would be at least as vulnerable as unaspirated [p] (if not more so) to becoming [f]/[ɸ] and subsequently [h]. But, even if there was no intermediate stage of [f]/[ɸ] in this case (I'm not sure how probable *p* > *h* would be without such a stage), is there any reason to think that aspiration would make [p] *more* rather than less resistant to the process that leads to [p] becoming [h]?

Thanks